# How can I construct my own LDAP packet in c#

Tags: c#, tcp, ldap, openldap, packet

I am writing a program that is intended for control system which only supports .NET 3.5 sp1 with very limited libraries. Directory services library  as well as using external dll is not an option. I am trying to construct a packet of LDAP by using TCP stream. Just for a test I added a byte array that I took from 
wireshark reading of the LDAP and put it into my tcpstream as a data. Do you have any suggestions on other ways?

```
    byte[] peer0_2 = { /* Packet 18 */
0x30, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0x02, 0x01,
0x03, 0x63, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3b, 0x04,
0x00, 0x0a, 0x01, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02,
0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x01, 0x78, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00,
0x87, 0x0b, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x6a, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74,
0x63, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x30, 0x84, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x17, 0x04, 0x15, 0x73, 0x75, 0x70,
0x70, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x74, 0x65, 0x64, 0x43, 0x61,
0x70, 0x61, 0x62, 0x69, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x74, 0x69,
0x65, 0x73 };


tcpc.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.10.20"), 636));

        NetworkStream ns = tcpc.GetStream();

        ns.Write(peer0_2, 0, peer0_2.Length);
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to read this: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4511

Comment: I read that page already but what wanted was that if its possible to use c# Network stream to send ldap data?

Comment: Sure, why not, LDAP is protocol over TCP.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I need more detail to even begin in c#

Comment: You have to be more specific. You need to implement protocol and you have full specification at the link above - which messages, how encoded, how transferred. What more details exactly you need?

Comment: Now I am stuck at how to attach ldap protocol into a tcp client. normally tcp client will attach my protocol to payload section instead of incapsulating an LDAP layer. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Find a library. You are engage on a Herculean task. Too broad.

Comment: I found this link that pointed me on how to create raw packet protocol. http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/clientserversocketnetworkcommunication8f_3.html